# [JAVA]How to add a element in a specific array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm trying to make a example with arrays in java, I want to do a library with some books sorted in categories, I want to use a `addBook` method to add the book in the categories array but I don't know how do it if I've many arrays, the goal is add the book in the same shell of categories, I'd 3 class called `Estante`,`Libros`,`libreria`.

```
package com.manzacatesSAS;

/**
 * Created by deborah on 7/09/16.
 */
public class Libreria    
{   
    Estante[] miedo     = new Estante[6];
    Estante[] comedia   = new Estante[6];
    Estante[] novelas   = new Estante[6];
    Estante[] romance   = new Estante[6];
    Estante[] comics    = new Estante[6];    
}

 package com.manzacatesSAS;   

/**
 * Created by deborah on 7/09/16.
 */
public class Estante {

    //attributes of Estante
    private int maxNumLibros = 6;
    //I guess this isn't necesay because if i use array,this only has 6 spaces
    private int maxPages = 3000;
    private String categoria = "";
    private int currentLibros = 0;
    private int currentPages = 0;

    public int getNumLibros() {
        return maxNumLibros;
    }

    public void setNumLibros(int maxNumLibros) {
        this.maxNumLibros = maxNumLibros;
    }

    public int getMaxPages() {
        return maxPages;
    }

    public void setMaxPages(int maxPages) {
        this.maxPages = maxPages;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor de Estantes
     *
     * @param categoria categoria de los libros
     */
    //No añadi los parametros restantes dado que al crear uno nuevo sus atributos deben estar vacios, o definidos por los atributos comunes.
    public Estante(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

        public void addBook(Libros x){
            if (currentPages + x.getNumPages() < maxPages && currentLibros < maxNumLibros) {
                currentLibros++;
            //I guess the array of the categorie to add the book would be here, and i think that use a for to add the book in the correct array.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: So your library hold 5 array of shelves, each with room for 6 shelves, for a total of 30 shelves. I was expecting to see an array of books (`Libros`) somewhere, but don’t see it? Also, an array leaves to you to keep track of how many of the spaces are actually used, it’s easier to use `ArrayList`, but of course, if this is to get experience with arrays, it should work.

Comment: Nice object-oriented thinking, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

See class design below (if you put the classes in separate files make them `public`).

In your main program you can do stuff like:

```
Library library = new Library();
Shelf shelf1 = new Shelf("Shelf 1");
library.addShelfToLibrary(shelf1);
Category fiction = new Category("fiction");
Category literature = new Category("literature");
Book book1 = new Book("Don Quixote");
book1.addBookToCategory(fiction);     // category for this book
book1.addBookToCategory(literature);  // another category for same book
shelf1.addBookToShelf(book1);
```

Here is the class design. You will need to add more methods, this is a skeleton.

```
class Library {
    private ArrayList<Shelf> shelves = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addShelfToLibrary(Shelf shelf) {
        if (!this.shelves.contains(shelf)) {
            this.shelves.add(shelf);
        }
    }
}

class Category {
    private String catname;

    public Category(String catname) {
        this.catname = catname;
    }

    public String getCatname() {
        return catname;
    }
}

class Book {
    private String title;
    private ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ArrayList<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
    public void addBookToCategory(Category category) {
        if (!this.categories.contains(category)) {
            this.categories.add(category);
        }
    }
}

class Shelf {
    private String shelfId;
    private ArrayList<Book> booksOnShelf = new ArrayList<>();

    public Shelf(String shelfId) {
        this.shelfId = shelfId;
    }

    public void addBookToShelf(Book book) {
        if (!this.booksOnShelf.contains(book)) {
            this.booksOnShelf.add(book);
        }
    }
}
```